# Disable dropdown item with CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I need to disable, deactivate or at least hide a dropdown item called `Private request` and I can only use CSS or Javascript to do so.

When I inspect the dropdown item it has the class `a.js-dropdown-list`. But every item in my dropdown has this class. So I can't just use `{display: none;}` because it will hide all options. Is there no more specific ID for every item in the drop down or can I deactivate items with Javascript?

Drop Down looks like this:

[image: drop-down menue]

Here the code (1st block is for the picker field, 2nd for the drop-down menue):

```
<div id="js-organization-picker">
    <sd-select class="js-share-with-organisation-picker is-private" data-type="link" data-id="customfield_10203" data-value="38" data-options="[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Private request&quot;,&quot;styleClass&quot;:&quot;is-private&quot;,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;locked&quot;},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Share with Testorganisation&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:38,&quot;icon&quot;:&quot;unlocked&quot;}]" resolved="">
        <a id="js-customfield_10203-dropdown-trigger" class="aui-dropdown2-trigger aui-button aui-button-link js-trigger customfield_10203-trigger select-dropdown-trigger aui-alignment-target aui-alignment-element-attached-top aui-alignment-element-attached-left aui-alignment-target-attached-bottom aui-alignment-target-attached-left active aui-dropdown2-active aui-alignment-enabled" aria-controls="customfield_10203-dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" tabindex="0" data-aui-trigger="" data-dropdown2-hide-location="js-customfield_10203-dropdown-container" resolved="" aria-expanded="true" href="#customfield_10203-dropdown">
            <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-locked">
            : : before
            </span> Private request
            : : after
        </a>
        <input name="customfield_10203" type="hidden" class="js-input" value="">
        <div id="js-customfield_10203-dropdown-container" class="hidden"></div>
    </sd-select>
</div>


<div id="customfield_10203-dropdown" class="aui-dropdown2 filter-dropdown aui-style-default js-filter-dropdown select-dropdown aui-layer aui-alignment-element aui-alignment-side-bottom aui-alignment-snap-left aui-alignment-element-attached-top aui-alignment-element-attached-left aui-alignment-target-attached-bottom aui-alignment-target-attached-left aui-alignment-enabled" role="menu" aria-hidden="false" data-id="customfield_10203" resolved="" style="z-index: 3000; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; transform: translateX(602px) translateY(918px) translateZ(0px);" data-aui-alignment="bottom auto" data-aui-alignment-static="true">
    <div role="application">
        <ul class="aui-list">
            <li>
                <a class="js-dropdown-item " href="#">Private request</a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li>
                <a class="js-dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="38">Share with Testorganisation</a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To be fair the scope here, this is a non-standard dropdown and would typically be an  `<input>` and a `<datalist>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist instead of a link/ `<a>` anchor tag.  A datalist is exactly what what designed for this

Comment: Can you please add a reference to the custom dropdown code.  It likely has a "selected" type event handler that can be hooked to.

Comment: Is it always the first element on the drop-down? does it show all the time?

Comment: Curious, why are there empty `<li></li>`?  If just to style CSS might be a better solution.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I edited the code . I hope it's the right thing i uploaded - after "<a id="js-customfield_10203-dropdown-trigger"... I can find an "event listener" button. Maybe that's what u were searching for?

Comment: @IgnacioCatalina yes it is always the first element in the drop down box but if there are more than one organizations to share with it is not the preselected anymore. Only if there is one share option ist is also the preslected option in the field

Answer (score 0):

E.g. you could give the dropdown item ids to identify them. In HTML this would look like this: `<p id="yourIdHere"></p>`

You can access this item through Javascript using the `document.getElementById()` function like this: `document.getElementById('yourIdHere').style.display = 'none';`

---

If you can't edit the existing html code, youi have to get the element by it's name/value. This is a bit difficult. You have to iterate through all elements of that type and evaluate each name/value. If you have found the one, you was looking for, you can edit/hide it. You would do so (untested):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); //div will be the name of the tag of your elements in the dropdown list 
var length = elements.length;
for (var i=0, item; item = elements[i]; i++) {
  if(item.value == "Private request") { //"Private request" is the name of the element we are looking for
    item.style.display = 'none'; //Hide the element
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is I cannot use any HTML, since I try to manipulate the code of this programm via Addon. I'm also not really firm with programming and certainly not with Jscript. This is the code I have but I can't manipulate with html. Is this even possible then?

Comment: Yeah, there is a way. It's a bit tricky, but here you got. I edited my answer.

Comment: item.value will return undefined

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

If I get you right there are plenty of elements with the same ID `js-dropdown-list` and you want to hide a specific one and there is no additional class for the element and you're not allowed to add specificity to it, let's say by adding of an additional class, you can do the following:

Grab all elements with this *id* by:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.js-dropdown-list'); // this is an array of these elements

let elementToHide = elements[n] // whene n is the number of that element

//hiding the element
elementToHide.style.display = 'none';
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Since my programming skills are not yet to be developed, I think there are no IDs for my items or I can't find them. I posted a code snipped of that block in my description so I might be wrong.

Comment: `'#a.somthing'` selects an ID 'a' not an element here, and since an ID MUST be unique, this would only select a single element.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you're correct, I thought letter _a_ is also used as an ID name. Fixed

Comment: Except you did not.

Comment: Okay, I got it. So you can solve your issue by the following code: let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.js-dropdown-list'); let elementToHide = elements[0] elementToHide.style.display = 'none';

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried the following and it worked for me: #customfield_10203-dropdown div .aui-list li:first-child {display: none;}. Next step will be to also change the preselected red option to "Share with ...", as in some cases, it is still "Private request".

Answer (score 0):

You could loot trough all '`js-dropdown-items`', check its `innerText` for 'Private request' and set its parentNodes display-property to `'none'`:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('js-dropdown-item');
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  if(list[i].innerText === 'Private request') list[i].parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<ul class="aui-list">
  <li>
    <a class="js-dropdown-item " href="#">Private request</a>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <a class="js-dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="38">Share with Testorganisation</a>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the following and it worked so far: `#customfield_10203-dropdown div .aui-list li:first-child {display: none;}`. Next step would be to change the preselected red text also to the "Share with organization" item.

Answer (score 0):

VannillaJS Solution `document.querySelectorAll(".aui-list > li")[0].style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I believe you will have to actually hide it OR use whatever you are using for this pseudo drop down (there was no reference in the question) to manage the disabled state if it provides that.  Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/disabled-elements.html

Get the element by its text and then hide it.  Might need the parent but this directly answers the question.  Note this could all be wrapped in a function and then called from where you wish.

```js
function HideByText(elId, findText) {
  let group = document.getElementById(elId).getElementsByClassName('js-dropdown-item');
  let found = Array.prototype.filter.call(group, function(el) {
    return el.innerText === findText;
  });
  found.forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  });
  return found;// in case you need the elements ref.
}

let foundFiltered = HideByText('customfield_10203-dropdown', 'Private request');
```

```html
<div id="customfield_10203-dropdown" class="aui-dropdown2 filter-dropdown aui-style-default js-filter-dropdown select-dropdown aui-layer aui-alignment-element aui-alignment-side-bottom aui-alignment-snap-left aui-alignment-element-attached-top aui-alignment-element-attached-left aui-alignment-target-attached-bottom aui-alignment-target-attached-left aui-alignment-enabled"
  role="menu" aria-hidden="false" data-id="customfield_10203" resolved="" data-aui-alignment="bottom auto" data-aui-alignment-static="true">
  <div role="application">
    <ul class="aui-list">
      <li>
        <a class="js-dropdown-item " href="#">Private request</a>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li>
        <a class="js-dropdown-item " href="#" data-value="38">Share with Testorganisation</a>
      </li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternate for parent would be:

Change `el.style.display = 'none';` to

```
if (node.parentElement) {
    el.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried the following and it worked for me: `#customfield_10203-dropdown div .aui-list li:first-child {display: none;}`. Next step will be to also change the preselected red option to "Share with ...", as in some cases, it is still "Private request".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS? Not an ideal solution, but it might be better than using JS for this.

```css
#js-organization-picker + .aui-dropdown2 .aui-list li:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

If you need to hide the first 2 elements, you could do something like:

```css
#js-organization-picker + .aui-dropdown2 .aui-list li:first-child,
#js-organization-picker + .aui-dropdown2 .aui-list li:first-child + li {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried tthe following: `#customfield_10203-dropdown div .aui-list li:first-child {display: none;}` and this worked since there is no more aui.list on the site. Next problem or better solution would be, that the auto selected option would also change. With my option the "Private request" option is just hidden in the dropdown but in some cases still preselected.